# Access repository in build time (Jenkins)

Tags: git, github, jenkins, ssh, cicd

I've faced with a problem of pushing to github repository during Jenkins' job execution. Jenkins clones repository using github app key, but when building script wants to make git push, it fails because it doesn't have required key. I've tried to clone it by ssh key, but everything stays the same. Is it possible to give Jenkins full access to my repository while it's building?

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to Jenkins user, you can create SSH key for it and add it do "deploy keys" (with write access) in your Git repo. However, you would have to do this in every jenkins agent node.

You could also use ssh-agent plugin https://plugins.jenkins.io/ssh-agent/

```
sshagent (credentials: ['github-creds']) {
    sh 'git push'
}
```

I guess you will have to configure git aswell to make a commit.